# How do I gunzip to a different destination directory?

Tags: linux, unix, gunzip

How do I gunzip to a destination directory other than the current one?

This did not work:

```
gunzip *.gz /putthemhere/
```

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Ask `gunzip` to output to standard output and redirect to a file in that directory:

```
gunzip -c file.gz > /THERE/file
```

`zcat` is a shortcut for `gunzip -c`.

If you want to gunzip multiple files iterate over all files:

```
for f in *.gz; do
  STEM=$(basename "${f}" .gz)
  gunzip -c "${f}" > /THERE/"${STEM}"
done
```

(here `basename` is used to get the part of the filename without the extension)

Comment: Creates the file, but does not preserve file ownership, permissions etc.  That may be good or bad depending on your precise situation.

Comment: how to gunzip to different location alongwith deleting the original file?

Answer (score 4):

If you need to extract a single file *and* write into a root-owned directory, then use `sudo tee`:

```
zcat filename.conf.gz | sudo tee /etc/filename.conf >/dev/null
```

If the file is coming from a remote source (i.e., `ssh`, `curl https`, etc), you can do it like this:

```
ssh remoteserver cat filename.conf.gz | zcat | sudo tee /etc/filename.conf >/dev/null
```

(Note that these examples only work for a *single* file, unlike the example *.gz, which is all gzipped files in the directory.)

Comment: For writing with root privileges, `sudo tee $filename >/dev/null` is a little more idiomatic than using `dd`.

Comment: @Toto @AulisRonkainen You should've approved [this suggested edit](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/1127854). The answerer, in their 2018-11-21 edit, meant to edit their answer to say `sudo tee` instead of `sudo dd`. The answerer replaced two instances, but it seems they just forgot to edit that part in the aforementioned suggested edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with > to redirect the result to the place you want.